# Callback is not a function after putting inside the event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Good day,

I'm trying to supply my eventSources whenever the button is triggered. The problem is, it doesn't work. It only works when it's on default data.

Here are my codes inside the data, it works:

```
data()
 return{
  eventSources: [{
    events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        axios.get(`/Info/Something1`).then(response => {
            callback(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, {
    events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        axios.get(`/Info/Something2`).then(response => {
             callback(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
             console.log(error);
        });
    }
   }]
}
```

But when I'm trying to put it inside my event button, then it doesn't work.

```
data(){ 
  return{
    eventSources:[]
  }
},
methods:{
    buttonIsClicked(){
        this.eventSources = [{
               events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                   axios.get(`/Info/Something1`).then(response => {
                      callback(response.data);
               }).catch(error => {
                      console.log(error);
               });
               }, {
               events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                   axios.get(`/Info/Something2`).then(response => {
                       callback(response.data);
                   }).catch(error => {
                       console.log(error);
               });
         }}]
    }
}
```

The error says after I put it inside my button click is `callback is not a function`

Thank you in advance I hope somebody helps me.

Comment: Are you *passing* a callback?

Comment: Yes my calendar, yes. It works when I put values of events inside the `data` but when I put it inside the button clicked, it doesn't work

Comment: Side note, your `data(){ eventSources: [] }` is not correct. Data should return an object of properties, so `data() { return { eventSources: [] } }`

Comment: Yes it is let me update that. I mistyped @Ohgodwhy

Comment: It works for me ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/133qy93n4l)). Can you provide a repro?

Comment: It works now @tony19 just a webpack bug.

Comment: I just have a new problem @tony19

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532088/data-object-inside-the-event-function-doesnt-work-and-resulted-to-undefined take a look at this @tony19