# Data object inside the event function doesn't work and resulted to undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having an undefined value when I put my object data inside the event.

Here are my codes:

```
data(){
    return {
       eventSources: [],
       myId: 1
    }
},
methods:{
   myMethod(){
     this.eventSources = [{
          events(start,end,timezone,callback){
              alert(this.myId); 
              axios.get(`/Something?id=${this.myId}`).then(response=>{
                  callback(response.data);
              }).catch(error=>{console.log(error);});
          }
     }]
   }
}
```

My alert is resulted to `undefined` but when I put my alert above the `this.eventSources = [{...]]` the alert has a value of `1`

I hope somebody helps me.

Comment: This wouldn't even compile. You can't have an object key of `this.eventSources =`. And that's just the first thing I saw. None of this looks like valid code of any language

Comment: I updated my question @Phil

Comment: Still not seeing how this would compile. I get an _"Unexpected token {"_ error for that `fn() { alert() }` syntax

Comment: Me too, I'm having a problem in order to access the `this.myId` inside the `events`

Comment: I suggest you start by writing syntactically valid JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `this` inside `events()` is not actually your Vue instance. You can fix the context by declaring `events` as an [arrow-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
this.eventSources = [{
  events: (start,end,timezone,callback) => {
    alert(this.myId);
  }
}]
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      eventSources: [],
      myId: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      this.eventSources = [{
        events: (start,end,timezone,callback) => {
          alert(this.myId);
        }
      }]

      this.eventSources[0].events(0, 1, 'UTC', data => console.log(data))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="myMethod">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you sir. You saved my day! Thank you for the new learnings :)

Comment: @jsonGPPD No problem :)